# Regular Expression to replace begin and end of string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider the following input:
BEGINsomeotherstuffEND

I'm trying to write a regular expression to replace BEGIN and END but only if they **both** exist.

I got as far as:

```
(^BEGIN|END$)
```

Using the following c# code to then perform my string replacement:

```
private const string Pattern = "(^guid'|'$)";
private static readonly Regex myRegex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var newValue = myRegex.Replace(input, string.empty);
```

But unfortunately that matches either of those - not only when they both exist.

I also tried:

```
^BEGIN.+END$
```

But that captures the entire string and so the whole string will be replaced.

That's about as far as my Regular Expression knowledge goes.

Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using this:

```
^BEGIN(.*)END$
```

And then replace the entire string with just the part that was in-between:

```
var match = myRegex.Match(input);
var newValue = match.Success ? match.Groups(1).Value : input;
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you really need a regex here. Just try something like:

```
if (str.StartsWith("BEGIN") && str.EndsWith("END"))
    str = "myreplaceBegin" + str.Substring(5, str.Length - 8) + "myreplaceEnd";
```

From your code, it looks like you just want to *remove* the beginning and end parts (not replacing them with anything), so you can just do:

```
if (str.StartsWith("BEGIN") && str.EndsWith("END"))
    str = str.Substring(5, str.Length - 8);
```

*Of course, be sure to replace the indexes with the actual length of what you are removing.*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use regular expressions as a parsing engine. However, you could just flip this on its head and say that you want what is between:

```
begin(.*)end
```

Then, just grab what is in group 1